# What are the different PC sync ports?

Tags: canon, cables

I have 3 devices and all of them seem to have different PC sync ports. Now which is which and what are the names of these ports? What cable is needed to connect all of them? I am attaching a picture of them.[image: PC sync ports]

Answer (score 6):

The three pictures you have included are all the same type connector, a female PC sync connector. A [male PC to male PC cord](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/682575-REG/Impact_10032370_PC_Male_to_PC.html) will connect to any of them.

<sub>PC in the context of flash photography has nothing to do with a personal computer. It is an abbreviation of *Prontor/Compur*. Prontor has its origins in the Italian word *pronto* (quick) and was a brand of shutter produced by Alfred Gauthier in the 1950s. *Compur*, derived from the word *compound*, was the shutter brand of the Deckel Company. Both companies were based in Germany and both counted Zeiss as an influential stockholder when they introduced the standard 1/8"-inch coaxial connector for shutter/flash synchronization.</sub>

Comment: +1 for product link :). I will wait a bit more before accepting an answer

Answer (score 6):

Why do you think they're different?  They all look like female PC sync ports and they'll  fit the same PC connector.  There really is only one "kind" of PC sync port; there's even an ISO standard for it: ISO 519.

The only possible difference is whether it's "screwlock"  (i.e., has threads on the outer-most side to secure the connector) or simply friction-fit, but I can't tell that from the pictures.  I just know my 5DMkII isn't screwlock, and my YN-622Cs are.  And that only matters **if** you have screwlock cables.  But the electrical connections are identical for both.  IIRC, it's sync on the inner post, and ground on the outside ring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The gap between the +ve and the -ve on the canon 7D port seems to be bigger than the rest. I will buy a male-to-male screwlock PC sync cable and report my results.

Comment: correction: I am talking about the gap between the inner post and the outside ring.

Comment: @CorruptedMyStack Possibly the difference, then, of the threads for screwlock.

Comment: I have ordered one with a screwlock hoping that it will work. There are only a few longer than 6ft on amazon. I want to experiment by putting the a pentax flash in manual that is not triggering perfectly as a optical slave.