# Wired Flash Trigger Speedlite 470ex-ai 5D mark iv

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash, cables

I was interested in getting a flash for my 5D Mark iv, specifically the Canon Speedlite 470EX-AI, however, I currently use a top handle on camera since I also do a decent amount of videography. I was wondering if it is possible to trigger the flash via a cable that I could plug into the camera rather than via the hot shoe, since that is how I currently use my top handle, and if so, what type of cable am I looking for.

I know that since I technically (or at least rarely) will ever have both in use at the same time, I can just remove one, but I'm just looking for an alternative, so that I don't have to keep switching between the too.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if it is possible to trigger the flash via a cable that I could plug into the camera rather than via the hot shoe?

Not unless you are willing to use the 470EX-AI strictly in manual mode. You'll have to make any settings changes directly on the flash. Also, without the communication capability provided by the contacts on your camera's hot shoe, the self-adjusting bounce capability of the new 470EX-AI will be rendered inoperative.

In short, you'll be able to tell the flash to "fire" via the 5D Mark IV's [PC port](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65976/15871), but you'll do so at the expense of reducing the 470EX-AI to the same capability as a $50, manual only, no frills flash. To use most of the capability 
of the 470EX-AI either the flash itself, a [wired hot shoe cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GMWEI8), or a TTL capable remote wireless trigger needs to be attached to the camera's hot shoe so that the data contacts located around the standard "fire" contact can be used for two-way communication between the camera and flash.

Comment: What about a wireless TTL transmitter with a passthrough hotshoe, such as the flashpoint R2 TTL tranismitter/receiver? Then @Roshan could attach the handle to the hotshoe of the transmitter. It'd add some bulk but would accomplish the feat while eliminating the cable.